# JNA - Structure creation error

Tags: java, c++, dll, struct, jna

I have the following C++ code:

```
typedef struct {
    int TabSock[1024];
    DWORD TabIP[1024];
    int NumSockConec;
} TTABSOCK;
typedef TTABSOCK *PTABSOCK;
```

And a function:

```
TTABSOCK __stdcall mt_connectlist(void);
```

The above function is in a DLL.
I am trying create that Struct in Java using JNA, but I'm not getting success. My programm gots an error and closes when I try execute that native function.

Below is my implementation for the struct in Java/JNA:

```
public class TTABSOCK extends Structure {

    public int[] TabSock = new int[1024];
    public DWORD[] TabIP = new DWORD[1024];
    public int NumSockConec;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not initialize the arrays...nah forget it, it should not be the problem..

```
public static class TTABSOCK extends Structure {

    public int[] TabSock = new int[1024];
    public DWORD[] TabIP = new DWORD[1024];
    public int NumSockConec;

    public static class ByReference extends TTABSOCK implements Structure.ByReference {};
    public static class ByValue extends TTABSOCK implements Structure.ByValue {};
}
```

Comment: what is the exception, if it is catched?

Comment: The JVM crashes when I call that function. I talked with some developers and they told me they have the same problem. We believe the DLL is with some error.

I am trying another function.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you're returning a structure by value.  By default, JNA Structure is treated as "struct *" in arguments and return types, so you need to indicate you want "struct" behavior instead in this case.

```
public interface MyLibrary extends StdCallLibrary {
    class TTABSOCK extends Structure {
        public static class ByValue extends TTABSOCK implements Structure.ByValue { }
        // ...
    }
    TTBASOCK.ByValue mt_connectlist();
}
```

Comment: Hi! I tryed return the structure by value, but doesn't work. I talked with some developers and they told me they have the same problem. We believe the DLL is with some error. I solved using another function. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The other thing to check would be the overall structure size and alignment.  If these do not agree between native and Java code, structures by value will not work.  Compare "sizeof(TTBASOCK)" in native code with TTBASOCK.size() in Java.